# Loop or map array inside the JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array of javascript objects like:

```
const arrayData = [
{ name: "campaign 1", date: "2022-05-13", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-05-25"},
                                                      {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-05-30"},
                                                      {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-05-31"}]
},

{ name: "campaign 2", date: "2022-06-19", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-08-12"},
                                                      {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-09-01"},
                                                      {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-06-08"}]
},

{ name: "campaign 3", date: "2022-07-11", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-06-13"},
                                                      {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-07-10"},
                                                      {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-08-01"}]
},
];
```

I want to convert it into this form:

```
const arrayData = [
{ name: "campaign 1", date: "2022-05-13", Planning:"2022-05-25", Funding: "2022-05-30", Delievery: "2022-05-31"},
{ name: "campaign 2", date: "2022-06-19", Planning: "2022-08-12", Funding: "2022-09-01", Delievery: "2022-06-08"},
{ name: "campaign 3", date: "2022-07-11", Planning: "2022-06-13", Funding: "2022-07-10", Delievery: "2022-08-01"}
];
```

I tried to do it this way:

```
let newData = [];
for (let i in arrayData) {
        newData.push({
          campaignName: arrayData[i].campaignName,
          date: arrayData[i].date,
          arrayData[i].milestones.map(item, index)=>(
            [arrayData[i].milestones[j].name]:
            arrayData[i].milestones[j].targetedDate,
          )
        });
      }
```

But, it didn't work for me. Kindly provide the solutions of it. Thanks

Comment: `const newArr = arrayData.map(({name, date, milestones}) => ({ name, date, ...milestones.reduce((o, {name, targetDate}) => { o[name] = targetDate; return o; }, {}) }));`

Answer (score 3):

This will iterate the `milestone` property only once for each object. That would be faster.

```js
const arrayData=[{name:"campaign 1",date:"2022-05-13",milestones:[{name:"Planning",targetDate:"2022-05-25"},{name:"Funding",targetDate:"2022-05-30"},{name:"Delievery",targetDate:"2022-05-31"}]},{name:"campaign 2",date:"2022-06-19",milestones:[{name:"Planning",targetDate:"2022-08-12"},{name:"Funding",targetDate:"2022-09-01"},{name:"Delievery",targetDate:"2022-06-08"}]},{name:"campaign 3",date:"2022-07-11",milestones:[{name:"Planning",targetDate:"2022-06-13"},{name:"Funding",targetDate:"2022-07-10"},{name:"Delievery",targetDate:"2022-08-01"}]}];

const formattedData = arrayData.map( obj => {

  const tempObj = {
    name: obj.name,
    date: obj.date
  }
  
  obj.milestones.forEach(milestone => {
    tempObj[milestone.name] = milestone.targetDate;
  });
  
  return tempObj;
});

console.log(formattedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#map` and object destructuring as in the following demo. This demo assumes that the milestones elements are always in the order `Planning, Funding, Delivery`. If the order is bound to be different, I'll provide a second demo that would work for whatever order they appear in.

```js
const arrayData = [ { name: "campaign 1", date: "2022-05-13", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-05-25"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-05-30"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-05-31"}] }, { name: "campaign 2", date: "2022-06-19", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-08-12"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-09-01"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-06-08"}] }, { name: "campaign 3", date: "2022-07-11", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-06-13"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-07-10"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-08-01"}] }],

      output = arrayData.map(
          ({milestones:[
              { targetDate:Planning },
              { targetDate:Funding },
              { targetDate:Delivery }
          ],
          ...rest}) => 
          ({...rest,Planning,Funding,Delivery})
      );
      
console.log( output );
```

**Alternatively ....**

You can use `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` as in the following demo. This should work for any order **AND NUMBER** of milestones.

```js
const arrayData = [ { name: "campaign 1", date: "2022-05-13", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-05-25"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-05-30"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-05-31"}] }, { name: "campaign 2", date: "2022-06-19", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-08-12"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-09-01"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-06-08"}] }, { name: "campaign 3", date: "2022-07-11", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-06-13"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-07-10"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-08-01"}] }],

      output = arrayData.map(
          ({milestones,...rest}) => 
          ({
              ...rest,
              ...milestones.reduce(
                  (acc,{name,targetDate}) =>
                  ({...acc, [name]: targetDate}), {}
              )
          })
      );
      
console.log( output );
```

**As for your code ....**

1. You introduced a property `campaignName` that does not exist in your data
2. Rather than use `Array#map` you can use `Array#reduce` in combination with the spread `...` operator as in the following demo:

```js
const arrayData = [ { name: "campaign 1", date: "2022-05-13", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-05-25"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-05-30"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-05-31"}] }, { name: "campaign 2", date: "2022-06-19", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-08-12"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-09-01"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-06-08"}] }, { name: "campaign 3", date: "2022-07-11", milestones:[{name:"Planning", targetDate: "2022-06-13"}, {name:"Funding", targetDate: "2022-07-10"}, {name:"Delievery", targetDate: "2022-08-01"}] }],

      newData = [];
      
for (let i in arrayData) {
    newData.push({
        name: arrayData[i].name,
        date: arrayData[i].date,
        ...arrayData[i].milestones.reduce(
            (acc, {name,targetDate}) =>
            ({...acc, [name]:targetDate}),{}
        )
    });           
}

console.log( newData );
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
arrayData.map(item => ({
    name: item.name,
    date: item.date,
    Planning: item.milestones.find(milestone => milestone.name === 'Planning')?.targetDate,
    Funding: item.milestones.find(milestone => milestone.name === 'Funding')?.targetDate,
    Delievery: item.milestones.find(milestone => milestone.name === 'Delievery')?.targetDate,
}))
```